# How Can I Create MasterPage In React-Router-Redux That Connect To Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, master-pages, router, react-router-redux

I want to create a masterpage that includes navigation bar and login-profile section. Login-Profile section will connect redux to get datas from reducer. How can i do it on App? App is also creating Provider with store parameter, so can i make its container? Where should i put my master page, or its items?

Note: Not Mainpage, MasterPage!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '../resources/redux/store';
import MainPage from './mainPage';
import Profile from './profile';
import Stream from './stream';
import Market from './store';

const store = configureStore();

export class App extends Component {

   render() {
     return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
            <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
            <Route path='/stream' component={Stream} />
            <Route path='/store' component={Market} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for confusion, we could add component's into provider as

```
   <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <MasterPage/>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
          <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
          <Route path='/stream' component={Stream} />
          <Route path='/store' component={Market} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </Provider>
```

So MasterPage can be container to use reducers.